# Error while trying to pull from a remote repository on Google App Engine

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I'm trying to pull from a remote repository located on Google App Engine and I'm getting the following error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file
specified fatal: remote error:

Invalid authorization credentials.

Please generate a new identifier:
https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

I followed the steps indicated in the link, but when I try to pull again, the error is still there.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: having the same issue.  Did you ever figure out?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions on the page and place the file in your `$HOME` directory with the filename `.netrc`

That worked for me.